# Autoplay Vimeo video on click in modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, vimeo, vimeo-api

How can I autoplay Vimeo video I have in iframe in bootstrap modal window on image click?

I've done this before using YouTube JavaScript API but have no idea how this works with Vimeo. I see they also have some API but could use some pointers how this would work.

First tried appending ?autoplay=1 to iframe video src attribute in modal on image click using jQuery but that didn't work.

When the modal hides before video is done I also need to stop() the video from running in background.

Any pointers in the right direction greatly helpful!!! Thank you!

Comment: I'm also trying to accomplish this with jQuery

Comment: Read this http://developer.vimeo.com/player/js-api it should tell you what you need to do. You could also try and walk around the api by manually triggering a click on the video when it loads $('.your-video').click()

Answer (score 5):

I tried the appending the iframe's source with '?autoplay=1' like you'd mentioned:

```
$("iframe")[0].src += "?autoplay=1";
```

Seems to work for me. I believe the iframe also needs to include '**allow="autoplay"**' though for example:

```
<iframe src="YOURVIDEOURL" width="640" height="360" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen allow="autoplay">
```

To stop the video on click - I imagine appending the src, removing '?autoplay=1' would then also work.

Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: This didn't work for me, I needed `&autoplay=1` instead of `?autoplay=1`

Comment: @RenzoTissoni If you have other URL parameters you must use `&` but if it's the first or only parameter you must use `?`. For example: `?controls=1&byline=0&title=0&autoplay=1`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with jQuery, I wrote a plugin which simplifies controlling a Vimeo video with standard jQuery notation.

https://github.com/jrue/Vimeo-jQuery-API

```
$("#yourvideo").play();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to autoplay vimeo video on an image click then this might be helpful, I had the same problem of playing video on image click but finally found this solution.

```
<div id="modal-Id">
   <div id="parent-div">
     <img id="vimeo-videoId" src="images/your-image.png" onclick="return imgClick();" />
   </div>
</div>

 function imgClick() {
                jQuery('#your-imageId').hide();  //hide image to play the video
                var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
                ifrm.setAttribute("src", "https://player.vimeo.com/video/123456789?autoplay=1");
                ifrm.style.width = "496px";
                ifrm.style.height = "277px";
                // add rest of your values
                ifrm.frameborder = 0;
                document.getElementById("your-parent-Div").appendChild(ifrm);  //append it to your parent div 
                return false;
            }
```